# Nginx isn't proxying requests that are just to the hostname, but proxies requests that have a path

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up a new app, and I'm trying to use Nginx to proxy the requests to the different docker containers. I can't get the "Welcome to nginx!" page to stop appearing for requests to the website (http://szabado.com/). If I append some path, it will proxy that, but it refuses to proxy requests with just the bare hostname.

I tried looking at the nginx [config pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/), but I couldn't see anything there that seemed relevant?

nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    # Use the default docker DNS host
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name szabado.com www.szabado.com;

        # Case insensitive, just match any path that starts with API and send it to the API container
        location /api {
            set $upstreamAPI http://goldyapi:8080;
            proxy_pass $upstreamAPI;
        }

        location / {
            set $upstreamUI http://goldyui:8080;
            proxy_pass $upstreamUI;
        }
    }
}
```

The Dockerfile to create the nginx container:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I expect it to display `Invalid Host header` as it does with any random path, but it displays the welcome page instead.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with a "default" virtual host. See if there is a default Nginx configuration file inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and remove it.

And modify your to be the default:

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     server_name szabado.com www.szabado.com;
...
```

Comment: my installation doesn't have a `sites-available` file. I had to remove `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Comment: That would be my second thought. All right then @szabado

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to remove `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. Updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN nginx -T
```